# mongo-mongoose how to make this query mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Models**

> Models -> **id, name, makeid**
>
> Makes ->  **id, name**

how to make this query mongoose using the make name and not the id ("mitsubishi") ?ex:

```
SELECT * FROM models
LEFT JOIN makes on models.makeid = makes.id
where makes.name = "mitsubishi"
```

How can realize this same query in mongo - mongoose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Model schema, is written like so:

```
makeid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Makes'}
```

Then you can do a population query like so:

```
Model.findOne({}).populate( {path:'makeid'});
```

This will return an object that looks like this:

```
{id:'mirage', 'name':'Mirage', makeid:{id:'mitsubishi', name:'Mitsubishi'}}
```

I would probably name the "makeid" field of Model to "make" to make it more idiomatic.

You'd also get the _id and any other properties. If you want to filter the properties add a select property:

```
{path:'makerid', select:'id name'}
```